# Is there an idempotent e in a ring $R$ such that the functor $T_e$, induced by $e$, is not full?

Tags: modules, functors, idempotents

Let $R$ be a ring and let $e$ be a non-zero idempotent in $R$. For each $R$-module $M$, define $T_e: M \rightarrow eM$, where $eM$ is the left $eRe$-module. For each pair of $R$-modules $M, N$ and each left $R$-homomorphism $f: M \rightarrow N$, let $T_e(f): f \mapsto f|_{eM}$. Then $T_e$ defines a covariant additive functor from $R-Mod$ to $eRe-Mod$.

Is there an example of ring $R$ and non-zero idempotent $e$ such that the above functor $T_e$ is not full?

Comment: In connection with Morita theory, an idempotent is called "full" if $ReR=R$.  I don't know if this will address the question, but it might be worth checking to see if it is called so if this functor is full.  It's very easy to find examples of non-full idempotents.

Comment: Thank you so much! May you provide references about an idempotent is called "full" if $ReR=R$?

Comment: Either of Lam's famous books (First course in noncommutative rings, Lectures on modules and rings)

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R=\begin{pmatrix}k&k\\0&k\end{pmatrix}$, the ring of upper triangular $2\times2$ matrices over a field $k$, let $e=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, so that $eRe\cong k$, and let $M=R$, so that $eM=\begin{pmatrix}k&k\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,M)$ is $3$-dimensional, but $\operatorname{Hom}_{eRe}(eM,eM)$ is $4$-dimensional, so $T_e$ can't be full.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.